# Removing letters from a string and only retaining numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, haml

I have an array `arr` in HAML, which is inside a loop.

```
- item.each do |grp, arr = []|
  - grp.section.each {|abc| arr.push(abc.values_with_units) }
```

For each iteration, the values and the units of them change. It might be `["23 mm", "34 mm", "56 mm"]` and in the next iteration it might be `["25 km/s m", "32 km/s m", "12 km/s m"]`. I want to get rid of the units and retain only the values: in case 1 `[23,34,56]`, and in case 2 `[25, 32, 12]`.

How can I achieve this in Ruby?

Comment: Tried and doesn't work for the array. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to_i ignores everything after numbers so you can do the following.

```
array = ['23 mm', '34 mm', '56 mm'] 
array.map(&:to_i)
# [23, 34, 56] 

array = ['25 km/s m', '32 km/s m', '12 km/s m']
array.map(&:to_i)
# [25, 32, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
array = ["23 mm", "34 mm", "56 mm"] 
array.select {|a| a[/\d+/]}.map(&:to_i)
# > [23, 34, 56]

array = ["25 km/s m", "32 km/s m", "12 km/s m"]
array.select {|a| a[/\d+/]}.map(&:to_i)
# > [25, 32, 12]
```